# How would you compare subgroup Stouffer Zs?

Tags: meta-analysis, combining-p-values

p-curve analyses (http://www.p-curve.com/) use significant p-values to estimate evidential value and effect sizes. To estimate evidential value, p-values are computed for p-values (pp-values), and these are converted to one-tailed, negative z-scores. These z-scores are summed and divided by the square root of the number of studies (Stouffer's method).

How would you conduct a subgroup analysis? With the p-values because they're unstandardized? With the z-scores because they *are* standardized?

Comment: Could I just conduct Fisher's Z-test? Z = (Z1 - Z2) / sqrt([1/(n1 - 3) + 1/(n2 - 3]) Z = Z difference / Z standard error

Comment: I believe this question is more fit for [stats.se].

Answer (score 1):

There seems no reason not to do this by just applying Stouffer's method separately to each sub-group. Note that in your comment you are mixing together the inverse normal transformation $z$ which is what you want with Fisher's inverse hyperbolic arctangent $z$ which is not what you want. There is a method for combining $p$-values named after Fisher but it is not the one you are talking about.

Comment: Thank you! I've been meaning to update this. It turns out I can do just as you've suggested. I can then take the difference between these two z-values and compute the p-value from the resulting z. The error rate is 5% when I run simulations.